# How do I erase one Access-Control-Allow-Origin from my headers in Laravel 4

Tags: angularjs, laravel, cors

Sorry my English. My Laravel project worked fine in my local machine with a yeoman project (Angular app inside a submodule git) into the public folder. But now I push my Laravel to my shared hosting, and when I try to access with Angular from my localhost:9000 to my host, Chrome shows:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://server.com/server/public/data. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://localhost:9000, *', but only one is allowed. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

I use [barryvdh/laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) and my config is:

```
'defaults' => array(
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => array(),
    'allowedHeaders' => array(),
    'allowedMethods' => array(),
    'exposedHeaders' => array(),
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => array(),
),

'paths' => array(
    'api/*' => array(
        'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
        'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
        'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
        'maxAge' => 3600,
    ),
    '*' => array(
        'allowedOrigins' => array('*'),
        //'allowedHeaders' => array('Content-Type'),
        'allowedMethods' => array('POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'),
        'allowedHeaders' => array('*'),
        //'allowedMethods' => array('*'),
        'maxAge' => 3600,
        'hosts' => array('*'),
    ),
),
```

I see Network tab in Chrome console:

```
Response Headers:
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:9000
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
```

How can I avoid two Origins? I only desire *. I have one .htaccess in my server with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*". Can you help me please? Thanks!

Update:
In laravel_server/public I has this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

Comment: Should I put this in laravel-cors isses on github? Can they help with this?

Comment: Did you check your htaccess? You can set headers there too

Comment: Thanks for answer. I update the question with the .htaccess content. Do I have something wrong?